# Firebase fetch data using .value observer is not working

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I get this error when I try to use .value in the observer

**Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value**

```swift
     @objc func load_data(){
        
        Database.database().reference().child("Food").observe(.value){ (snapshot: DataSnapshot) in
        
              if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]{
                for child in snapshot.children {
              let FoodimageText = dict["image"] as! String
              let FoodnameText = dict["name"] as! String
              let FoodpriceText = dict["price"] as! String
                
              let post = FoodModel(FoodimageText: FoodimageText , FoodnameText: FoodnameText , FoodpriceText: FoodpriceText)
              

                self.foodlist.append(post)
                self.tableview_controller.reloadData()
                
                }
            }
            
            }
        
          
        }
```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Comment: On Stack Overflow, don't show pictures of code or text.  Copy the code into the question itself and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search.

Comment: got it. Thanks for letting know

Answer (score 1):

Your type casting is failing. You have used force typecast(as!) when accessing dictionary fields, in the case of when you actually ask for a field/key that doesn’t exist in the dictionary it’ll return nil and type cast to String would fail, like you experience there, or one of the fields/keys are actually not type cast-able(if there’s such a word) to String type. Hopefully this helps you out...

Tip: you probably are better off calling tableView reload data outside of the for loop.

It’s difficult to give you a solid answer without seeing what your DB looks like right now.

Comment: I am not it is not able to locate the fields from firebase

Comment: You also have to use child[“image”] instead of dict[“image] , this applies for all keys you try to access via dict.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of dict use Child here and dont use force unwrap and reload Data outside the loop

```
@objc func load_data(){
        
        Database.database().reference().child("Food").observe(.value){ (snapshot: DataSnapshot) in
        
              if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]{
                for child in dict.values {
             if let FoodimageText = child["image"] as? String,
              let FoodnameText = child["name"] as? String,
              let FoodpriceText = child["price"] as? String {
                
              let post = FoodModel(FoodimageText: FoodimageText , FoodnameText: FoodnameText , FoodpriceText: FoodpriceText)
              
                  self.foodlist.append(post)

                  }
               
                
                }
              self.tableview_controller.reloadData()
            }
            
            }
        
          
        }
```

Comment: I am getting this error:  **Value of type 'NSEnumerator.Element' (aka 'Any') has no subscripts**

Comment: I solved it replacing **for child in snapshot.children** with **for child in dict.values**

Comment: I have another problem with it. It adds the changed data to the previous data

Comment: you need to change `.value` to `.childAdded`

Comment: I get an empty tableview